# Dual Cisco ASA 5505 passing RSTP in transparent mode

Tags: firewall, cisco, cisco-asa, rstp

I'm looking at moving to colocation and one area being discussed is networking redundancy.  I can get a dual feed from a two different datacentre switches configured with Rapid Spanning Tree Protocol to give me an active passive supply.

I'm looking at using the Cisco ASA 5505 as a firewall.  If I get two and put them in transparent mode, should I be able to put them 'in line' before my switches and the RSTP pass through ok and remove the loop?

I realise that I would have to keep the configuration between them in sync manually.

If this is possible, but considered to be a bad idea, what alternatives exist for a low cost HA firewall solution.

EDIT:
I'd just want to add for clarification that I was looking to make sure my hardware was redundant i.e. two firewalls, not just having 2 network links from the datacentre through a single firewall.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same configuration: two Layer 2 connections to the data center provider, and a single gateway IP address.

You don't need RSTP to make this work. Instead, you can put the ASA's in to active/passive failover mode. When the primary fails, the backup will assume your external IP and continue working. The data center will just see this as the device moving to a different switchport.

Comment: I had seen some ASA's supported A\A or A\P HA, however, the 5505 is the lowest range and I don't think supports HA natively.  I was looking at the 5505 due to our low bandwidth requirements and for budget reasons.

Comment: You're right. I didn't realize that the 5505's don't support failover.

Comment: Although, since I wrote the last comment I've just had someone tell me that with the security plus licence it supports Active Passive.  I haven’t had it confirmed yet.